# Obj-C variable from NSString?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsstring

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Get an ivar or property from a NSString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6286549/get-an-ivar-or-property-from-a-nsstring)
>   [Remove @“” from NSString or typecast NSString into variable name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5719201/remove-from-nsstring-or-typecast-nsstring-into-variable-name)

Let's say I have:

```
MyClass *myVar = [[MyClass alloc] init];
```

and I have an `NSString *myString = @"myVar";`

Is there any way to retrieve the instance of the var based on the string I have?

Comment: Take a look to this question :
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6286549/get-an-ivar-or-property-from-a-nsstring](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6286549/get-an-ivar-or-property-from-a-nsstring)

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of that question.  I think he's asking for a way to obtain an object by its variable name.

Comment: Also [Use NSString as object name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684991/use-nsstring-as-object-name) and [Convert an NSString into the name of a constant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5542835/convert-a-nsstring-into-the-name-of-a-constant) and [Using a string representing the name of a variable to set the variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5680284/)

Answer (score 3):

At run time the identifier myVar means nothing, it's replaced by an address in memory.  If you want to be able to obtain objects by name, you need to use an `NSDictionary` or mutable dictionary e.g.

```
NSDictionary* map = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: 
                        [[[MyClass alloc] init] autorelease], @"myVar", nil];
```

Then access as follows:

```
[map objectForKey: @"myVar"];
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is an instance variable, just use `valueForKey:`.   If it is a local variable, you are out of luck.  If it is a global, you can do it, but it is ugly, slow and beg's the question of "why?!".

---

You'll have to provide more information as to what you are trying to do.  By definition a local variable is only valid within the scope within which it is defined.  Given that, it is hard to imagine a situation where you would need to access a local variable symbolically where there isn't also a better/cleaner/easier way.